# Execute partial SQL query based on user condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

Is it possible to execute only a portion of a full query, based on the condition chosen?
For example I have 4 Tables (Table_A, Table_B, Table_C and Table_D), I would like to execute only the portion of the union query, say for example, related to Table_B. I would like results of Table_B alone from the below query. Is it possible?

Sample query:

```
select name,date,start_time,end_time,status from 
(select name,date,start_time,end_time,status from Table_A
union
select name,date,start_time,end_time,status from Table_B
union
select name,date,start_time,end_time,status from Table_C
union
select name,date,start_time,end_time,status from Table_D
 )
where name like '%' and date like '200824'
```

Comment: Why can't you just leave the other tables out of the query?

Comment: Well it depends on user's selection, if no table is selected, the full query should run, if one Table is select, I want only that portion of the query to run @Nick

Comment: btw I would recommend also tagging your questions with `sql`, they will get seen by a much wider audience.